# Does this shape have a name? (A 'spherical circular triangle' ???)

Tags: geometry, terminology, triangles, spherical-geometry

This shape is formed by 3 'small' circles on the surface of a sphere, each touching the other 2.

[image: Region bounded by 3 small circles]

On a plane, the shape is called a 'circular triangle' (refer to Wikipedia). In this particular example it is called a 'circular horn triangle'.

[image: Circular Triangle in a plane]

On a sphere, we can create a 'spherical triangle' using 3 'great circles', from Wikipedia 'the spherical geometry equivalent of line segments in plane geometry'.

[image: Spherical triangle]

So I would be grateful if anyone could direct me to the correct or commonly used name for the shape formed by 'small circles on a sphere' or alternatively, is there a convention for using either 'spherical circular triangle' or 'circular spherical triangle'?

Many thanks

Comment: Is it really necessary to give it a name?

Comment: I don't know of any names

Comment: They are just called triangles on a shape

Comment: Hyperbolic triangle?

Comment: Somewhat similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/209716/305862). The problem with these triangles is that they aren't determined at all by their vertices, deprecating their interest !

Comment: Thanks for your replies. In response to Intelligenti pauca, It is useful to have the conventional name so I can find and reference/credit previous work and perhaps my own publications be found by others.

Comment: I have just discovered architects use the word 'pendentive' to describe the structure with this shape (that is used to support domes).